# Is there a possibility to give a javascript function the innerHTML of the element it is called from as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that takes a String as a parameter to do certain things. I want to bind that function to a button so it is called onclick and takes the innerHTML of the element as a parameter, is there any possibility to that without giving the button an id or without queryselector?

```
<button onclick="myFunction(myString)">Name XY</button>
```

There are about 500 Elements like this so i wanna avoid giving each one a unique element

Comment: Yes. You simply access the event’s currentTarget, which points to the element where the event handler is bound to. Then it’s a matter of accessing the innerHTML property of event.currentTarget.

Comment: event delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation so you add one click handler.

```js
document.querySelector("#wrapper").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var button = e.target.closest("button.action");
  if (button) {
    console.log(button.textContent);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <button class="action">1</button>
  <button class="action">2</button>
  <button class="action">3</button>
  <button class="action">4</button>
</div>
```